# How to fix common error causing multiplexed LED segments to flash and dim

Tags: circuit-design, design, multiplexer, led-matrix

I bought an electrical engineering book and was surprised to see the following figure showing how to use a microcontroller to multiplex 4 LEDs using only 4 pins:

[image: Microcontroller multiplexing 4 LED's with 4 MCU pins.]

This seemed right, logically, but wrong electrically, because a multi-segment display using this circuit would appear terribly dim with all 8 (or 9) segments sharing just one resistor like this.

Here is a simulation of the minumum subset of the circuit that would show the problem.  When both LEDs are on, they dim each other because they are sharing current, so they show at half brightness.  You can see the problem below from 100ms to 110ms when both LEDs fall from 2.7mA to 1.35mA.

[image: LTSpice simulation showing LED's at half power when both are on.]

I have actually seen this with commercial products.  Sports scoreboards in particular, which are both big **and** highly visible.  When you share only one resistor across all 9 segments (including decimal point), the output is only 11% of the original brightness.

Here are how the power sources are defined for the above simulation:

[image: LTSPice power definitions and a trace graph of them.]

The V2 trace is slightly offset to make it easier to see.

========

EDIT:

This was a question I thought I knew the answer to, so you will see my answer below.  I thought the book was wrong, and I was wrong.  I think that I was thinking of one whole digit being on at one time.  But I do see this display problem.  So, what causes the kind of display anomaly which I see in the real world, that makes digits dim when all of the segments are on?

Comment: i think that you are misunderstanding  how the circuit is supposed to function .... try time multiplexing the LEDs ... it is probably not meant for 7 segment displays

Comment: actually, the circuit could be used for 7 segment displays ... D1 and D3 would be two segments of one digit ... D2 and D4 would two segments of another digit ... the digits themselves would be time division multiplexed

Comment: I would indeed delete the question as all it shows is that you didn't understand what time multiplexing is, which is probably explained in the text of your book. It's of no long-term value as a question and driving multiplexed LEDs has been covered in other questions on the site. No harm done but best deleted :-)

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the brightness of the display from "jumping around" (flashing, actually) based on how many segments at a time are lit, the right answer is that every LED should have its own resistor.  The following LTSPice trace shows how it improves performance by maintaining full brightness when the two LEDs are on at the same time (small amount added to I(D4) to offset the trace for improved viewing):

[image: Schematic showing each LED having its own resistor, causing current to stay at full brightness when both are on.]

Each LED really needs to have its own resistor.

Comment: This is, well, not quite right. For a 4x4 display, only 2 resistors are needed if only 2 LEDs are lit at a time, which would be the case if they were multiplexed as 2x2.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the schematic, but you need to be clear how the display multiplex is working.

If you consider V3/V4 as the 'digit' select, only one of these should be high at a time. Then V1/V2 will be segment drives.

So you have a truth table as follows:

```
V4  V3  V2  V1 =>  D1   D2   D3   D4
0   0   x   x      off  off  off  off --- all digits off

1   0   1   1      off  off  off  off
1   0   1   0      on   off  off  off
1   0   0   1      off  off  on   off
1   0   0   0      on   off  on   off

0   1   1   1      off  off  off  off
0   1   1   0      off  on   off  off
0   1   0   1      off  off  off  on 
0   1   0   0      off  on   off  on 

1   1   x   x                         --- not allowed
```

In other words, when V4 is high, LEDs D1/D3 are active; V3 high, LEDs D2/D4 are active. Because V4 and V3 are *never* allowed to be on at the same, current only flows through one LED in the 'on' row; the other LED in the 'off' row is not forward biased.

Redraw the diagram as a 2x2 matrix, and this becomes clear:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0eQCwm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You would expand on this to an arbitrary row x column size as needed for your display.